# Backbone.js collection getting multiple models

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

You can get a `model` from the `collection` by using `collection.get(id)`;
but i want to get mulitple models. The `get` only gets 1 models.
I now use this piece of code, but it doesn't look pretty or feels good for performance. Anyone knows a better way to select an array of models from the collection?

```
var models = this.collection.filter(function(model){
    return _.indexOf([1,2,3,4], model.get('id')) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just need 4 items, your code iterate whole collection.

Following code is better performance by iterating only size 4 array.

```
var models = _.map([1,2,3,4], function(id) {
    return collection.get(id);
});
```

Comment: ofcourse! The other way around :) take the array as the starting point, not the collection. Thanks!